# Valgrind shows the debugging result,but the result isn't right

Tags: c++, debugging

When I just run my program:ns-server everytime, it will show me that it decrypts message fail, but when I use valgrind try to find why this error happens, it works fine. Every time when I use valgrind to debug it, it works fine.
the valgrind result is :

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./ns-server
==44887== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==44887== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==44887== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==44887== Command: ./ns-server
==44887== 
first get nextlen 564
nextlen is 564
==44887== Thread 2:
==44887== Invalid read of size 1
==44887==    at 0x6C49: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:427)
==44887==    by 0x100134E6F: StringBuffer::setString(char const*) (in ./ns-server)
==44887==    by 0x100159A4F: XString::setFromAnsi(char const*) (in ./ns-server)
==44887==    by 0x100025396: CkRsa::DecryptStringENC(char const*, bool,  CkString&) (in ./ns-server)
==44887==    by 0x1000130EA: My_RSA::MyDecryption(char*, CkString&) (RSAsample.cpp:52)
==44887==    by 0x1000021C1: Server::Register(char*, int, char*) (Server.cpp:164)
==44887==    by 0x100001EAB: Server::Evaluate_MSG(void*) (Server.cpp:75)
==44887==    by 0x409898: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==    by 0x409729: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==    by 0x40DFC8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==  Address 0x100b3f150 is 0 bytes after a block of size 128 alloc'd
==44887==    at 0x47E1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==44887==    by 0x1000020F4: Server::Register(char*, int, char*) (Server.cpp:154)
==44887==    by 0x100001EAB: Server::Evaluate_MSG(void*) (Server.cpp:75)
==44887==    by 0x409898: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==    by 0x409729: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==    by 0x40DFC8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==44887==
```

This is part of the result.
In this result, it mentions:

```
by 0x100134E6F: StringBuffer::setString(char const*) (in ./ns-server)
==44887==    by 0x100159A4F: XString::setFromAnsi(char const*) (in ./ns-server)
==44887==    by 0x100025396: CkRsa::DecryptStringENC(char const*, bool,  CkString&) (in ./ns-server)
```

But these 3 functions come from static library which I download them from http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vcCkRsaRef.html   does this mean the error actually happen in these functions? Why when I run with valgrind, my project can output the right result?When I run it without any debugging tool, it will output "decrypt fail". Valgrind will change something related to my program?

My code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
Server myServer(SERVER_PORT);//initialize server's port num,set up socket

myServer.Start();
return 0;
}

int Server::Start()
{

send_public_key server_pub_key;
server_pub_key.heads.random=random()%10;
server_pub_key.heads.request_type=PUBLICKEY;
server_pub_key.heads.length=sizeof(send_public_key);

strcpy(server_pub_key.pubkey,server_rsa.publickey);

TCPServer.SetupListen(PortListen,Evaluate_MSG,"",0,PUBLICKEY,(char *)&server_pub_key,server_pub_key.heads.length);
    return 0;
}

int TCPConnect::SetupListen(int port, void * trifunc(void *),char * refuseMSG,int refuseLen,int pub,char *msg,int length)
{
if((mi_SocketToListen=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1)
{
    printf("create socket failed\n");
    return errno;
}

struct sockaddr_in ts_SocketAddrToListen;
ts_SocketAddrToListen.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
SetupSocketAddrToTarget(NULL, port, ts_SocketAddrToListen,1);
if( bind(mi_SocketToListen,(struct sockaddr *)&ts_SocketAddrToListen,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
{
    printf("establish socket failed!\n");
    return errno;
}
if(listen(mi_SocketToListen,99)==-1)
{
    printf("listen failed\n");
    return errno;
}
while (1)
{
    int ti_sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in ts_sockaddr;
    socklen_t ti_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if((ti_sockfd=accept(mi_SocketToListen,(struct sockaddr *)&ts_sockaddr,&ti_size))==-1)
    {
        printf("accept user failed\n");
        return errno;
    }
    if (threadlist.size() < mi_MaxConnection)
    {

        if(pub==80)//if this needs me to send a public key immediately afther i accept it
        {

            SendMsg(ti_sockfd, msg,length);

        }

        mm_clients.insert(std::pair<int,struct sockaddr_in>(ti_sockfd,ts_sockaddr));

        pthread_t tp_threadfd;

        pthread_create(&tp_threadfd,NULL,trifunc,(void *)&ti_sockfd);

        threadlist.push_back(tp_threadfd);

    }
    else
    {
        SendMsg(ti_sockfd, refuseMSG, refuseLen);
        CloseConnect(ti_sockfd,NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
};

void * Server::Evaluate_MSG(void *arg)
{

int socketfd = *((int *) arg);

header checkheader;
int err;
while (true)
{
    err = 0;

    char * msg;
    char *ip;
    ip=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    memset(ip,0,sizeof(char)*INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    int nextlen=Server::TCPServer.GetNextlen(socketfd);

    msg=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*nextlen);
    memset(msg,0,sizeof(char)*nextlen);

    msg=Server::TCPServer.Receive(socketfd, nextlen);

    //Server::TCPServer.Receive(socketfd,msg);
    struct sockaddr_in sender_ip;
    memset(&sender_ip,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    sender_ip=Server::TCPServer.GetInfoBySocket(socketfd);

    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&sender_ip.sin_addr,ip,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    memset(&checkheader,0,sizeof(header));
    memcpy(&checkheader,msg,sizeof(header));
    switch(checkheader.request_type)
    {
        case REGISTER:
            err = Register(msg, socketfd,ip);

            break;
        case LOGIN:
            err=Login(msg, socketfd,ip);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    free(ip);
    free(msg);
    if (err<0)
    {
        cout<<"error!"<<endl;
        pthread_exit(0);
    }
}

}

int Server::Register(char *msg,int sockfd,char *ip)
{
request_register reg;
memset(&reg,0,sizeof(request_register));
 memcpy(&reg,msg,sizeof(request_register));



if(reg.real_pass!=REAL_PASS)
{
    //ignore
}
else
{
    send_user_success success_err;
    success_err.heads.random=random()%10;
    success_err.heads.length=sizeof(success_err);
    CkString user_name_outData;
    char *recv_username;
    recv_username=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*LENGTH_CIPHERTEXT);
    memset(recv_username,0,sizeof(char)*LENGTH_CIPHERTEXT);
    memcpy(recv_username,reg.username,sizeof(char)*LENGTH_CIPHERTEXT);

    server_rsa.MyDecryption(recv_username,user_name_outData);
    //it decrypt fails

    cout<<"after returning:"<<user_name_outData.getString()<<endl;
```

-------------------Above is part of function of Register(), it is too long, I just post part of it----------------

```
bool My_RSA::MyDecryption(char *ciphertext,CkString &outData)
 {
 rsaDecryptor.put_EncodingMode("hex");
 rsaDecryptor.ImportPrivateKey(privatekey);
 bool userPrivateKey;
 userPrivateKey=true;

 const char *cipher;
 cipher=ciphertext;


const char * decryptedStr ;
decryptedStr= new char[SAY_MAX];
memset((char *)decryptedStr,0,sizeof(char)*SAY_MAX);

 bool test=(char *) rsaDecryptor.DecryptStringENC(ciphertext, userPrivateKey, outData);//(decryptedStr, userPrivateKey);
if (!test) {
    cout<<"decrypt failed"<<endl;
    return false;
}

return true;

}
```

The error is: it will shows "decrypt failed" when I run without any debug tool, but it will decrypt definitely with valgrind. 
This is header(part):

```
static std::map <string,struct user_info> user_info_map;//string is user's name
static My_RSA server_rsa;

class Server
{
public:
Server(int p);

protected:

static TCPConnect TCPServer;

public:
int PortListen;


protected:
static int Register(char *msg,int sockfd,char *ip);
static int Login(char *msg,int sockfd,char *ip);
static int Lock_Un_Out(char *msg,int sockfd,int lock_unlock);

static int Check_User(int sockfd);
static int Send_User(char *msg,int sockfd);

static int Update(char *msg,int sockfd);
public:
int Start();

static void * Evaluate_MSG(void *arg);
};
```

The error is part is that it decrypts fail, but I don't think it is related to the function of `DecryptStringENC` because when I run it with valgrind or Xcode, it works fine frequently.

Comment: Yes, valgrind changes your code by instrumenting it. That may change results of memory operations. Running under valgring or any other debugging tool also changes timing which may change multithreaded program behaviour. **Have you investigated what could cause "Invalid read of size 1"? Would you like to post your code?**

Comment: I try to find the the reason, by it says:Invalid read of size 1
==44887==    at 0x6C49: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:427)
==44887==    by 0x100134E6F: StringBuffer::setString(char const*) (in ./ns-server)       I cannot see what's inside the function of StringBuffer::setString(char const*), it is not coded by me, I download it from website(Does this sentence means this error is related with this function). I'd like to post my code, but it will post at least 200 lines of related code. I will post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I see why an error happens. When I pass ciphertext into `MyDecryption(char *ciphertext,CkString &outData)` 
I set the size of it is 128bytes(Because when I use strlen to see the ciphertext's size, it shows 128). But I sudden think about that maybe I should malloc ciphertext with size of 129 bytes because '/0' will be attached to a string. Then, problem solves!!!!!!!

Comment: `std::vector` might help you solve bunch of problems in your code.